# Laravel different objects groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I merge two different objects into one? I want to show 2 tables on a timeline, and I need to group them by date of creation. If I try to show only one table it works fine, but I would like to combine them both by date. So if there exist two rows in different tables that have the same date of creation, I would like them grouped by that date.

```
    $comments = array_slice(WPComment::with('recipe')->orderBy('comment_date',
        'desc')->get()->groupBy('comment_date')->toArray(), 0, 5);
    $favorites = array_slice(WPFavorite::with('user')->orderBy('date_time',
        'desc')->get()->groupBy('date_time')->toArray(), 0, 5);
```

I have tried with the `$object1->merge($object2)` but that obvieusly doesn't do a complete merge of elements, as there is some rewriting done. Merging arrays with `array_merge()` does basically the same thing. Is there some one-line solution without the need to write some nasty raw's or double for loop gibberish?

**EDIT**:

JSON example before

```
obj1:{
     id: 1
     title:'blah',
     date: 1.1.2001
     }
obj1:{
     id: 2
     title:'blah blah',
     date: 31.4.2301
     }

obj2:{
     id: 1
     notTitle:'blah',
     somethingSomething : 'something'
     date: 31.4.2301
     }
```

JSON example after:

```
1.1.2001:{
        obj1:{
             id: 1
             title:'blah',
             date: 1.1.2001
             }
        }
31.4.2301:{
        obj1:{
             id: 2
             title:'blah blah',
             date: 31.4.2301
             }
        obj2:{
             id: 1
             notTitle:'blah',
             somethingSomething : 'something'
             date: 31.4.2301
             }

        }
```

Comment: How will one merged item look like?

Comment: Top JSON figure will be the date, and then level below there may be each type of object, depending whether their dates match

Comment: Post the example: objects before and after merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem with `array_merge_recursive()` method.

So now complete solution:

```
$comments = array_slice(WPComment::with('recipe')->orderBy('comment_date',
            'desc')->get()->groupBy('comment_date')->toArray(), 0, 5);
$favorites = array_slice(WPFavorite::with('user')->orderBy('date_time',
            'desc')->get()->groupBy('date_time')->toArray(), 0, 5);

return array_merge_recursive($comments, $favorites);
```